# Counting telemetry intersections with a polygon in R

Tags: r, intersection, tracking, trajectory

I am currently tracking animals in national parks and have lat/long and date/time data for individuals and a polygon shapefile for the park boundary. I want to know how many times individuals leave the park boundary each month and at what time of day. In nearly every instance, the individuals return to the park, so I need to account for directionality or count every other intersection.

At the moment, I am converting the raw data into telemetry paths as an ltraj object with the 'adehabitatlt' package. However, I cannot seem to trim the ltraj objects to the polygon, nor does it retain the associated time data for individual segments.

In the below example, I would want to know how many times and when the ibex leave the sps polygon:

```
library(adehabitatLT)
library(sp)

data(ibex)

##Sample Polygon
x_coord <- c(895000,  898000,  898000, 895000, 895000)
y_coord <- c(2031000, 2031000, 2033000, 2033000, 2031000)
xy <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)
p = Polygon(xy)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
```

Comment: Are you assuming the ibex travel in straight lines between point locations? So that if, for example, you have two locations outside *but the line between them clips a corner* the ibex has gone in and then gone out between those locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `sp` because most of the packages that support it are being retired from the end of 2023, and everyone is being advised to move to `sf`.

Here's a code to detect when ibex is leaving a polygon :

First, I convert ibex dataset to spatial point. I assume that projection is NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II (EPSG:27572) because it work with this one but **you should provide your projection** if you want better answering.

```
library(adehabitatLT) # get ibex data
library(sf) # spatial vector
library(dplyr) # data manipulation
library(tmap) # plotting result

data(ibex)

# Convert data to spatial point
ibex1 <- ibex[[1]] |> 
   filter(!is.na(x) | !is.na(y)) |> 
   st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 27572) |> 
   arrange(date)

# Create polygon
xy_coords <- data.frame(x = c(895000,  898000,  898000, 895000, 895000),
                        y = c(2031000, 2031000, 2033000, 2033000, 2031000))

poly <- st_as_sf(xy_coords, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 27572) |> 
   summarise() |> 
   st_cast("POLYGON") |> 
   st_convex_hull()

# find points inside poly
ibex1 <- ibex1 |> 
   mutate(is_inside = st_intersects(geometry, poly, sparse = FALSE)[,1])
```

When an ibex is leaving, the next point is not inside poly. I use `lead` function to shift up column `is_inside`.

| is_inside | lead(is_inside) | is_leaving |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| FALSE | NA | FALSE |

```
# detect leaving
ibex1 <- ibex1 |> 
   mutate(leave_poly = ifelse(is_inside & !lead(is_inside), "leave", NA))
```

You now have a column that detects the last points before leaving the polygon, in this case the sixth point on 2003-06-02 at 04:00:00.

You can check the result below by converting point to path.

```
# check result
path <- ibex1 |> 
   arrange(date) |>
   summarise(do_union = FALSE) |>
   st_cast("LINESTRING")

tm_shape(path)+
   tm_lines()+
tm_shape(poly)+
   tm_borders(col = "red")
```

Comment: Very clever use of lead! This is perfect for what I was looking for, thanks!